# jq select from date value after X days from now

Tags: date, time, jq

i have this one json response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "b8895839-52d3-40e1-8c86-20463f38fec4",
    "created": "23.08.2016 17:11:56"
  },
  {
    "id": "294374c0-0fb9-4ab6-853c-e0a11fde4906",
    "created": "26.08.2016 11:22:38"
  }
]
```

I want to return ids that the last created date is > 2 days from current date

how i can do that?

```
jq 'def ago(days): now - (days*24*3600);
.[] | select ( .created | sub("\\.[0-9]*";"") < ago(2) )| .id'
```

this one does not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Input: date in "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss" format;
# returns true iff the date is more than (24 * days) hours
# in the past relative to `now`
def older(days):
  (now - (strptime("%d.%m.%Y %T") | mktime)) #  seconds 
  >  (days*24*3600);
```

Example:

```
"30.1.2018 17:11:56"
| older(2)
```

emits `true`.